# Producing a read-only copy of a class, howto

Tags: java, casting

Given the following UML representation, how can i get an instance of a `BullDog` , that only has getter methods exposed?

- Instance of the `BullDog` should not have any of the setter methods available.
- Instance of the `BullDog` should only have getter methods (3 of them) available

Basically the question is .. what do i cast `new BullDog` to?

[image]

Comment: btw...what if myDog.getMetabolism() comes back as something "unhealthy". Your interface name will be kind of counter-intuitive

Comment: and why can only healthy pets get metabolism??  Surely all pets can return a metabolism rate and only then can healthiness be determined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since HealthyPet and Pet are unrelated there's nothing you can cast to that will give you all 3 getter methods(getMetabolism(),getName() and getAge()).  Now if HealthyPet extended Pet (and I'm really not sure why it doesn't) you'd be in business.  Because then you could cast to HealthyPet, return that interface, and a caller would only see the 3 getter methods (of course I'm talking without fancy introspection which should allow them to discover everything).

Answer (score 1):

You need HealthyPet to extend Pet. Then you cast your BullDog instance to HealthyPet.